# How can I prevent Windows Security dialog from appearing when users download a static file?

Tags: coldfusion, internet-explorer-9, powerpoint

I have a ColdFusion template that serves up static files (PDF, Word, PowerPoint, etc.) via CFCONTENT.

For a PowerPoint file - which can't be opened *IN* the browser, like a PDF - Internet Explorer (IE) 9 prompts you to Open or Save the file. When you click Open, a Windows Security dialog window appears asking for a user name and password.

[image: Windows Security dialog]
(I removed the website address for privacy purposes)

This behavior does not occur in IE8, nor does it occur when click "Save".

How can I prevent this Windows Security dialog from appearing, as it degrades the user experience and causes confusion?

Comment: What reason does it give? It sounds like your client PC is set to run PowerPoint as admin; that should not happen.  Something is wrong with your client.

Comment: @SLaks I've reproduced this with two other users, including myself. I am not running PowerPoint as Admin.

Comment: @SLaks No reason, just a Windows Security dialog as above.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to monitor the network traffic when you click on the link to download the file. Do this on a machine that does not work as well as one that does work and compare the traffic. At some point the machine that is not working must be receiving a 401/403 response and the browser is then prompting for credentials.

Are the users able to enter their credentials and then successfully open the file? If so, are those the same credentials as the ones that were used to log into the workstation? Are you also using a `cfheader` tag in combination with the `cfcontent` tag?  If so, are you specifying the Content-Disposition to be `inline` or `attachment`? Is your website in IE's "internet" or "intranet" security zone on these machines?

IE9 is obviously more secure than IE8 and this may come down to some setting that is "turned on" in IE9 but was not in IE8.